# calculate first,second,third derivative on 3d image

Tags: image, matlab, 3d, derivative

really i have a problem to calculate first , second , third derivative on 3d image with matlab.

i have 60 slice of dicom format of knee mri  , and i wanna calculate derivative .

for 2d image when we want to calculate derivative on x or y direction ,for example we use  sobel or another operator in x direction for calculate derivative on x direction .

but in 3d image that i have 60 slices of dicom format , how can i calculate first, second ,and third derivative on x ,y,z directions . 
i implement like this for first derivative    :

F is 3d matrix that has all slices. [k,l,m] = size(F);

but i think it's not true .please help me , really i need your answers .

how can we calculate first, second, third derivative  on x ,y ,z directions .?

case 'x'

```
D(1,:,:) = (F(2,:,:) - F(1,:,:));
D(k,:,:) = (F(k,:,:) - F(k-1,:,:));
D(2:k-1,:,:) = (F(3:k,:,:)-F(1:k-2,:,:))/2;
```

case 'y'

```
D(:,1,:) = (F(:,2,:) - F(:,1,:));
D(:,l,:) = (F(:,l,:) - F(:,l-1,:));
D(:,2:l-1,:) = (F(:,3:l,:)-F(:,1:l-2,:))/2;
```

case 'z'

```
D(:,:,1) = (F(:,:,2) - F(:,:,1));
D(:,:,m) = (F(:,:,m) - F(:,:,m-1));
D(:,:,2:m-1) = (F(:,:,3:m)-F(:,:,1:m-2))/2;
```

Comment: Your code is good for the first derivative. Just repeat? 2nd derivative-> derivative of the derivative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function for that! Look up https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgradient3.html, where there are options to indicate the kind of gradient computation: sobel is the default.

If you'd like directional gradients, consider using https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgradientxyz.html, which has the same options available, but returns the directional gradients Gx, Gy and Gz.

```
volData = load('mri');
sz = volData.siz;
vol = squeeze(volData.D);
[Gx, Gy, Gz] = imgradientxyz(vol);
```

Note that these functions were introduced in R2016a.

Comment: great, amazing , thanks a lot, can i use Gaussian filter instead of  some predefined filters like sobel  ? and if i use ix instead of original image , ixx will be in output?

Comment: If you'd like to gaussian blur the image, you could pre-filter it with a gaussian kernel too. Depending on your definition of what ix and ixx is, I believe taking a derivative of a derivative image should give you the second derivative.

Answer (score 0):

The "first derivative" in higher dimensions is called a gradient vector. There are many formulas to numerically approximate the gradient, and one of the most accurate approaches is disccused in a recent paper: "High Order Spatial Generalization of 2D and 3D Isotropic Discrete Gradient Operators with Fast Evaluation on GPUs" by Leclaire et al.

Higher order derivatives in more than one dimension are tensors. The "second derivative" in particular is a rank-2 tensor and has 6 independent components, which to the lowest order approximation are

```
Dxx(x,y,z) = (F(x+1,y,z) - 2*F(x,y,z) + F(x-1,y,z))/2
Dyy(x,y,z) = (F(x,y+1,z) - 2*F(x,y,z) + F(x,y-1,z))/2
Dzz(x,y,z) = (F(x,y,z+1) - 2*F(x,y,z) + F(x,y,z-1))/2
Dxy(x,y,z) = (F(x+1,y+1,z) - F(x+1,y-1,z) - F(x-1,y+1,z) + F(x-1,y-1,z))/4
Dxz(x,y,z) = (F(x+1,y,z+1) - F(x+1,y,z-1) - F(x-1,y,z+1) + F(x-1,y,z-1))/4
Dyz(x,y,z) = (F(x,y+1,z+1) - F(x,y+1,z-1) - F(x,y-1,z+1) + F(x,y-1,z-1))/4
```

The "third derivative" will be a rank-3 tensor and will have even more components. The formulas are lenghty and can be derived by considering a Taylor series expansion of F up to the 3rd order